# Scrolling Text program

Tags: c, string, gets

This is part of a larger program I'm trying to write, but I seem to be stuck on this part for some reason, and I'm hoping someone will explain why I'm having this issue.

So what I want to focus on in this post is taking in an integer which specifies how many words will follow. Then, I want to take in each word and print it out immediately.

This is what I have.

```
    int main(){

        int i;
        int numWords;
        char word[100];



        scanf("%d", &numWords);

        for(i=0;i<numWords;i++){
            gets(word);
            printf("The word is %s\n", word);

        }

    return 0;
}
```

I have an input file which reads:

```
5
Hello
world
this
is
happening
```

This is what is being output

```
The word is
The word is Hello
The word is world
The word is this
The word is is
```

Like I said, this is only part of what I need to do, but figuring this out will help me finish the rest.

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets()`, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun.

Comment: [The program didn't crash](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KECkQRHEKDanvjhH).

Comment: If you have crashes, then run in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and see exactly where in your code the crash happens. Also take a look at all variables and check that their values look appropriate.

Comment: Max size of word would be 100. No risk of getting higher, so I can just use fgets(word, 100, stdin);

Comment: I fixed the crashing and didn't edit the post, sorry. I'll update with new issue.

Comment: You should use `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);` instead of using magic numbers.

Comment: Guess: `scanf("%d", &numWords);` -> `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin); sscanf(word, "%d", &numWords);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%d", &numWords);
```

to

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
sscanf(word, "%d", &numWords);
```

so that the `fgets()` will read newline character after number and the first `gets()` won't read it and stop.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I appreciate it!

If you don't mind one last thing, my next step was taking in an integer immediately after word. Should I be using scanf? When I tried with scanf, the integer remained the same for two iterations of the loop.